# What does "Class* &cls" mean in C++'s function definition?

Tags: c++

I know Class *cls is a pointer, and Class &cls takes the address, but what is

```
void fucction1( Class *&cls)
```

If I have `Class c`, what should I pass to `function1()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Besides, what [James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632528/what-does-class-cls-mean-in-cs-function-definition/4632533#4632533) explained in [his response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632528/what-does-class-cls-mean-in-cs-function-definition/4632533#4632533), let me add one more important point to it.

While you can write `Class* &` (**reference to pointer**) which is perfectly valid in C++ only, you cannot write `Class& *` (pointer to reference), as you **cannot** have **a pointer to a reference** to any type. In C++, pointer to reference is illegal.

§8.3.2/4 from the language specification reads,

> There shall be no references to
>   references, no arrays of references,
>   and **no pointers to references**.

---

> If I have Class c, what should I pass
>   to function1()?

You can write your calling code like this:

```
Class *ptrClass;

//your code; may be you want to initialize ptrClass;

function1(ptrClass);

//if you change the value of the pointer (i.e ptrClass) in function1(),
//that value will be reflected here!
//your code
```

Answer (score 8):

For a type `T`, `T*` is a pointer to an object of type `T`, so `Class*` is a pointer to a `Class` object.

For a type `T`, `T&` is a reference to an object of type `T`, so putting them together, `Class*&` is a reference to a pointer to a `Class` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class c;
Class* c_ptr = &c;
function1(c_ptr);
```

Would work. But note that rvalue-references is only possible with C++0x which most compilers haven't fully implemented them. Thus the following wouldn't work:

```
Class c;
function1(&c);
```

Answer (score 0):

As said, a reference to a pointer to Class.

- you pass a `Class *` to the function
- the function may change the pointer  to a different one

This is a rather uncommon interface, **you need more details** to know what pointers are expected, and what you have to do with them.

Two examples:

**Iteration**

```
bool GetNext(Classs *& class)
{
   if (class == 0)  
   {
     class = someList.GetFirstObject();
     return true;
   }

   class = somePool.GetObjectAbove(class); // get next
   return class != 0;       
}

// Use for oterating through items:
Class * value = 0;
while (GetNext(value))
   Handle(value);
```

**Something completely different**

```
void function (Class *& obj)
{
    if (IsFullMoon())
    {
      delete obj;
      obj = new Class(GetMoonPos());
    }
}
```

In that case, the pointer you pass must be new-allocated, and the pointer you receive you need to pass either to `function` again, or be `delete`'d by you.