# What is exact meaning of expression that is pointer and reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, syntax, reference

While looking at code of binary search tree, I came across this expression,

```
Node *&t;
```

Where Node is struct. Why `t` needs to be pointer and reference at same time?

Regards

Comment: It's a reference to a pointer. Pointers and references read a lot better if you have the * or & next to the type name so it's just considered a single type instead of a type with modifiers. Node*& t;

Comment: Why closing, why downvotes, please suggest whats wrong. I understand its duplicate. But I did not found exact word for it. So couldn't find answer.

Comment: A question closed as a duplicate doesn't necessarily mean you did anything wrong - it's simply to keep the site clean. I can't really explain the downvotes, but perhaps it had something to do with lack of understanding basic syntax (if you want to learn a language, you should start with a good book or course, both of which should explain this in sufficient detail - and yes, I know there can be bad books or courses which don't explain it sufficiently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reference to a pointer (since [pointers to references are illegal in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632762/why-pointers-to-a-reference-is-illegal-in-c)). This means, that `t` represents some variable, which, in turn, is a pointer to `Node`.

It is hard to judge, what this variable is used for without some code, but the scenario may look like the following:

```
void MoveNext(Node * & t)
{
    t = t->next;
}

// (...)

Node * current = head;
MoveNext(current);
// Now current points to second item
```

Comment: Pointers to references are illegal because they don't make any sense.

Comment: Oh does that mean instead of using Node**, I am using reference to pointer.

Comment: Yes, both `Node**` and `Node* &` can be used in this case, though the first one requires more error-checking, is less safe and less convenient to use. The main goal is to pass the pointer to a function in such way, that it can be modified.

Comment: @Jefffrey Pointers to references are illegal because references don't necessarily have an address.  But the reason this is a reference to a pointer isn't because pointers to references are illegal; it is because the reference and pointer "operators" in a type expression have right to left associativity.